# System of five quintic equations, find all real roots

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

Solve 
$$\begin{cases}
(x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3})^5=3x_{4}\\
(x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4})^5=3x_{5}\\
(x_{3}+x_{4}+x_{5})^5=3x_{1}\\
(x_{4}+x_{5}+x_{1})^5=3x_{2}\\
(x_{5}+x_{1}+x_{2})^5=3x_{3}
\end{cases}$$
all real roots, it seems not easy.

My try:let $$u_{1}=x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3},u_{2}=x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4},u_{3}=x_{3}+x_{4}+x_{5},u_{4}=x_{4}+x_{5}+x_{1},u_{5}=x_{5}+x_{1}+x_{2}$$

then
$$\begin{cases}
u^5_{1}=-u_{1}+2u_{2}-u_{3}+2u_{4}-u_{5}\cdots\cdots (1)\\
u^5_{2}=-u_{1}-u_{2}+2u_{3}-u_{4}+2u_{5}\cdots\cdots (2)\\
u^5_{3}=2u_{1}-u_{2}-u_{3}+2u_{4}-u_{5}\cdots\cdots (3)\\
u^5_{4}=-u_{1}+2u_{2}-u_{3}-u_{4}+2u_{5}\cdots\cdots (4)\\
u^5_{5}=2u_{1}-u_{2}+2u_{3}-u_{4}-u_{5}\cdots\cdots(5)
\end{cases}$$

I think this is nice problem, why someone downvote it?

Comment: There's an obvious solution of $x_1 = ... = x_5 = 0$. I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think he's asking whether or not this system of equations has any complex, non-real solutions.

Comment: Not all roots are real; For instance, $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = x_4 = x_5 = \pm\dfrac{i}3$. Of course, there are also real roots; For instance, $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = x_4 = x_5 = \pm\dfrac13$ and $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = x_4 = x_5 = 0$.

Comment: Thank you everyone,How find it?

Comment: and why close it? Thank you

Comment: 1) downvote not download. 2) Amid a little bit unclear, the question itself doesn't have any big problem. It is probably the wording of your original version that attract the downvote. It sounds as if you are "commanding" someone to do the problem for you. 3) I don't downvote this question. I upvote this instead.

Comment: It's nice equalition! But  Now I can't find it, and I don't know other one have solution?+1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you wish to find all real solutions to your system of five equations.

**Claim 1:** If at least three of the $x_i$ are $\ge\frac13$, then they all are.

Case 1: Suppose there are at least three adjacent $x_i$ (that is, with indices cyclic, as per the equations) which are $\ge\frac13$. For example, $x_1,x_2,x_3\ge\frac13$. Then 
$$\begin{array}\\
1\le x_1+x_2+x_3\\
1\le (x_1+x_2+x_3)^5=3x_4\\
\end{array}$$
So $x_4\ge\frac13$. Then similarly, $x_5\ge\frac13$.

Case 2: Assume otherwise. Then there are two non-adjacent $x_i$ with values $\lt\frac13$. For example, say $x_4,x_1\lt\frac13$, and all others $\ge\frac13$. Then
$$\begin{array}\\
(x_3+x_4+x_5)^5=3x_1\lt 1\\
(x_4+x_5+x_1)^5=3x_2\ge 1\\
\end{array}$$
So
$$\begin{array}\\
-x_3-x_4-x_5\gt -1\\
+x_4+x_5+x_1\ge 1\\
\end{array}$$
Adding these two inequalities gives $-x_3+x_1\gt 0$, or $x_1\gt x_3$, a contradiction.

**Claim 2:** If at least three of the $x_i$ are $\le\frac13$, they all are. Proof is exactly the same as Claim 1, except reverse the inequalities.

**Claim 3:** If at least three of the $x_i$ are $\ge 0$, they all are. Proof is exactly the same as Claim 1, replacing $\frac13$ and $1$ with $0$.

**Claim 4:** If all the $x_i\ge 0$, and at least one is $0$, they all are. Suppose $x_4 = 0$, and one or more of $x_1,x_2,x_3 \gt 0$. Then $x_1+x_2+x_3 \gt 0$, so $(x_1+x_2+x_3)^5 = 3x_4 \gt 0$, a contradiction. So $x_1=x_2=x_3 = 0$, and likewise $x_5=0$.

**Claim 5:** If all the $x_i\le \frac13$, and at least one is $\frac13$, they all are. Suppose $x_4 = \frac13$, and one or more of $x_1,x_2,x_3 \lt \frac13$. Then $x_1+x_2+x_3 \lt 1$, so $(x_1+x_2+x_3)^5 = 3x_4 \lt 1$, a contradiction. So $x_1=x_2=x_3 = \frac13$, and likewise $x_5=\frac13$.

**Claim 6:** If at least one $x_i$ is positive, the maximum of the $x_i$ is $\ge\frac13$. Let $x_4$ say be equal to the maximum. Then

$$\begin{array}\\
x_1+x_2+x_3\le 3x_4\\
(x_1+x_2+x_3)^5 \le (3x_4)^5\\
3x_4\le(3x_4)^5\\
1\le 3x_4
\end{array}$$

**Claim 7:** If all $x_i$ are positive, $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5\le\frac53$. 
Let
$$
u_1=x_1+x_2+x_3\\
u_2=x_2+x_3+x_4\\
u_3=x_3+x_4+x_5\\
u_4=x_4+x_5+x_1\\
u_5=x_5+x_1+x_2\\
s=x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5\\
$$

By the Generalized Mean Inequality

$$\frac{\Sigma u_i}5 \le (\frac{\Sigma u^5_i}5)^\frac1 5$$

The left hand side is $\frac{3s}5$, and the right hand side is $(\frac{\Sigma 3x_i}5)^\frac15 = (\frac{3s}5)^\frac15$. And $\frac{3s}5 \le (\frac{3s}5)^\frac15$ implies $\frac{3s}5 \le 1$, or $s\le\frac53$.

Now with these seven claims, we can complete our argument.

Let us suppose at least three of $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ are non-negative: otherwise, replacing each by its negation will also satisfy the equations, with three non-negative. Then by Claim 3, all $x_i$ are non-negative. If one is zero, then by Claim 4, they are all zero. This is one solution. So assume now that all $x_i$ are positive.

Consider the number of $x_i$ in the interval $(0, \frac13]$. If there are at least three, then by Claim 2 all five are in this interval. So by Claim 6, the maximum is $\frac13$. By Claim 5, they are all $\frac13$. This satisfies the original equations, and so this is a second solution.

So now we can assume at most two of the $x_i$ are in $(0, \frac13]$. So there are at least three in $(\frac13, \infty)$. By Claim 1, any remaining $x_i$ are $\ge\frac13$. So $\Sigma x_i\gt\frac53$, contradicting Claim 7.

For a third solution, multiply the previous solutions through by $-1$. So there are only three real solutions: $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=x_5=1/3, -1/3, \text{or } 0$.